# Dygraph multiple plots - turn them on and off with R and dySeries options

Tags: r, facebook, shiny, xts, dygraphs

Good afternoon everyone,
I am discovering [dyGraph for R](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) and it is an amazing tool.
I need to plot only two variables ("Lifetime.Engaged.Users" & "Lifetime.Post.Total.Reach") of my 32 variables xts matrix.

***My problem*** is as follow, even if I specify the two series I want to be plotted (with *dySeries*), dyGraph plots all the 32 variables, making the graph totally unreadable.
Here is the code.

```
# Read the insights from xls export 
facebook.insight <- read.xlsx(
    "Facebook Insights (Post Level)", 
    sheetIndex = 1)
# Convert the facebook insights to a Time Series with library(xts)
facebook.insight.TimeSerie  <- xts(
           facebook.insight[,-7], 
           order.by = facebook.insight$Posted
    )
# Plot the desired series that are ("Lifetime.Engaged.Users" & 
#"Lifetime.Post.Total.Reach") with dyGraph package 

dygraph(facebook.insight.TimeSerie, main ="Facebook Insights") %>%
    dySeries(name = "Lifetime.Engaged.Users", label = "Engaged Users") %>%
    dySeries(name = "Lifetime.Post.Total.Reach", label = "Post Total Reach")
```

**In conclusion, what shall I do to plot only the two desired series** (*"Lifetime.Engaged.Users" & "Lifetime.Post.Total.Reach"*), without having to create 33 xts dataframes ?

Comment: you can try subsetting your `xts` before plotting, in the dygraph, replace `facebook.insight.TimeSerie` by `facebook.insight.TimeSerie[,c("Lifetime.Engaged.Users","Lifetime.Post.Total.Reach")]`